# How do I show visitor count in my page using google analytics?

Tags: jersey, analytics, visitor-statistic

How do I show visitor count on my home page using google analytics?

I want this in my Jersey web application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console
2. Click 'Create Project'
3. Create a credentials - OAuth 2.0 Client ID
4. Select Application Type: Web application.
5. Under IAM & ADMIN, select 'Service Account' and create Service
   Account.

   - Select role to project -> owner.
   - Check 'Furnish a new private key' and select P12.(it will download this file).
6. Copy this service account id.
7. Log in to your Google Analytics account
8. Click 'Admin' in the bottom-left corner
9. Click the 'User Management' tab
10. paste this service account id in add permission field and click Add
     button.
11. Set up the sample https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java
12. Set the service account and path to the p12 file.
13. Run the Program.